# Visual Studio 2015. Add existing item using code (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

How can i add an existing item to my visual studio project using c++ code?

```
//This function creates a simple .txt file
void Example::CreateFile(){
  ofstream outputFile("SimpleFile.txt");
  outputFile << "Hello";
  outputFile.close();

  //Here i want to use code to include the file created above to my vs2015 project.

}
```

**Edit:** To be more detailed. [This is how you can add new items in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDBli.jpg). Using this option you can select the file you want to add to your project. In my case i will select the SimpleFile.txt i created before using code and [now the file is included in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5enzZ.png). But you have to do it manually (the way shown in the first image).

I want to know if exist a way to do the same but automatic, so when i create a file using the function, it will be added to my project and compiled to include the file in the source files.

Thanks.

Comment: Downvoted because is unclear what you're asking

Comment: There is no benefit to any files that are not compiled other than visibility to users. And the file created in your snippet of code would be in the output folder (and not part of the source files).

Comment: @crashmstr i also want that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Project Generator for that, like CMake.